# Update ACF User Radio Button After Gravity Form Submit

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gravityforms

having a issue with getting a ACF field associated with a user profile to update after a gravity form submission. As it stands, this logic currently does nothing :(. So i'm hoping someone can help out. Here is waht I have so far:

```
//changes studio status after those forms submit
function update_user_tour_status($entry, $form){
    $user_id = $entry['created_by'];
    $state = update_user_meta('user_'.$user_id, 'artist_tour_status', 'studio');
}
add_action('gform_after_submisson_7', 'update_user_tour_status', 10, 2);
```

So it should be pretty straight forward I would image, but it just seems to do nothing.

Comment: Why are you prefixing the user ID with `user_`, in your `update_user_meta` call? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/ says it is supposed to be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [update_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/)

```
//changes studio status after those forms submit
function update_user_tour_status( $entry, $form ){
    $user_id = $entry['created_by'];
    $state   = update_user_meta( $user_id, 'artist_tour_status', 'studio' );
}
add_action( 'gform_after_submisson_7', 'update_user_tour_status', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `update_user_meta();` [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/), the first argument should only be the user's ID. `user_` does not need to be appended, as the function expects an integer, not a string. Drop the `user_` prefix, and it should work like a charm.